# "No overload for function "instantiate" takes 4 arguments"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello Im following a Unity tutorial made by Quill18. In my code Im trying to instantiate some hex prefabs.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HexMap : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GenerateMap ();
    }
    public GameObject HexPrefab;
    public void GenerateMap()
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) 
            {
                Instantiate (HexPrefab, new Vector3 (column, 0, row), Quaternion.identity, this.transform); //this is the exact code he used and was working for him
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The instantiate method is giving me trouble. Even the online documentation says I can pass 4 arguments but I am getting the error "No overload for function "instantiate" takes 4 arguments".
The script component is attached to an Empty.

Comment: Ensure you use version 5.4 or above.

Comment: i checked and it says that it is up to date: "The unity editor is up to date. currently installed version is 5.3.8p2"

Comment: The first reflex to have when you encounter a problem with an API is to go see its documentation ....

Comment: Glad you have found your answer. Though I'm still confused why you get "is up to date" message, while it's actually not the latest stable version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unity3D's 5.3 documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) shows that there are no definitions for Object.Instantiate that takes four parameters. However, [starting from 5.4](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html), you can use the Instantiate method as you intended to do so. Make sure that your Unity version is the same as the tutorial's.

A workaround to change the parent of your Instantiated GameObject, for Unity 5.3.x, is as follows:

```
public void GenerateMap()
{
    GameObject GO;
    for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) 
        {
            GO = Instantiate (HexPrefab, new Vector3 (column, 0, row), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; 
            GO.transform.parent = this.transform;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made an edit to move the declaration of GO to a broader scope, to avoid new allocation at every single step in the loop.